# Worksheet Change Event Fires Upon Function Update, but not Worksheet Change

Tags: vba, excel

My worksheet contains a cell that calls a function, which (naturally) returns a value. If the value is "Filter", then the cell font color is supposed to change. Prob is, it only changes when I refresh the function in the cell, not when there is a worksheet change anywhere else in the worksheet. I need the font color to change upon any worksheet change. Why is this not the case?

```
 Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
 Application.EnableEvents = False

'change font color to red for filter losses
If Target.Column = 2 Then
    If Target.Text = "Filter" Then
            Range("B" & Target.Row).Font.ColorIndex = 3 
    End If
End If

Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

I have also tried using worksheet calculate event, shown below, but this code does not work at all:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_calculate()
Application.EnableEvents = False

Dim cell As Range

For Each cell In Me.UsedRange.Columns("B").Cells
    If cell.Text = "Filter" Then
        Range("B" & cell.Row).Font.ColorIndex = 3
    End If
Next cell

Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: `Worksheet_Change` doesn't track changes when formulas recalculates. You should use [`Worksheet_Calculate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838823(v=office.15).aspx) event instead

Comment: @simoco, indeed I tried worksheet calculate, but my code failed to work at all (no error, just no results). Please see update above. Any idea why my worksheet calculate code does not produce the desired result?

Comment: try to use `For Each cell In Intersect(Me.UsedRange,Me.Range("B:B"))`

Comment: @simoco, yep, that worked. I need to add Intersect to my toolbox. Thanks as always.

Comment: Can you share the function that populates the target cell? is it used in a formula eg `=myUDF()` if not how is it populated?

Comment: @NickSlash, the function itself is 300 lines. The function call is: "=ILLookup(EB_Case_No, B40,G40, EB_LBE, EB_UBE)". Simico's Intersect suggestion worked. Thanks for your effort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As follow up from comments, this one works:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_calculate()
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

    Dim cell As Range, rng As Range

    Set rng = Intersect(Me.UsedRange, Me.Range("B:B"))
    If rng Is Nothing Then GoTo ExitHere

    For Each cell In rng
       If cell.Text = "Filter" Then
           cell.Font.ColorIndex = 3
       End If
    Next cell

ExitHere:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Exit Sub
ErrorHandler:
    Resume ExitHere
End Sub
```

I slightly changed your event-hadler to be more reliable.
Also you can add `rng.Font.ColorIndex = 1` just before loop to reset previous font color.